# C# Selenium Selecting drop down Value

Tags: c#, selenium

i have searched multiple times but still cant solve this issue. 
tried many ways from different sites, mainly using SelectElement.
i need to select the Dropdown and select the Value as Public.

as soon as i right click and inspect on the dropdown values, the dropdown closes.

[Dropdown image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv7nO.png)
[Dropdown inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb3ZJ.png)

here is the code i have right now:

```
~~~ login code =>
DriverChrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://steamcommunity.com/my/edit/settings");                
new SelectElement(DriverChrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.ProfilePrivacyDropDown"))).SelectByText("Public");
Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div"))).SendKeys("Public");
Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[4]/div"))).SendKeys("Public");
Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[7]/div"))).SendKeys("Public");
Wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div[10]/div"))).SendKeys("Public");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the problem try this:

```
DriverChrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://steamcommunity.com/my/edit/settings"); 
DriverChrome.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.ProfilePrivacyDropDown")).Click();

DriverChrome.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[@class='popup_menu_item' and contains(text(),'Public')]")).Click();
```

You will need to add a wait for element there after the first click.

What i did was click the drop down and selected inspect on the element while taking a screenshoot.

Got this: 
[image]

Hope this helps.